# Blank MVC grid with correct number of rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, razor, devexpress

I have a DevExpress MVC grid that uses the following .BindToLINQ:

```
.BindToLINQ(typeof(MyContext),
    "Results",
    ((s, e) =>
    {
        e.KeyExpression = "ResultId";
        MyContext db = new MyContext();
        e.QueryableSource = from r in db.Results
            where r.SearchId == @Model.SearchId
            select r;
    })
```

Normally, for other grids, SQL Profiler shows an initial select of the top 128 rows (since my page size is 100), then individual selects on each ID to fill in the data needed. On the first load of this grid, it performs the top 128 query but never does the individual selects, producing a blank grid with the correct number of rows. I have turned on the VS2010 settings to break on all exceptions when they are thrown, but I do not encounter one.

If I sort the blank grid, the rows appear as expected.

How can I go about debugging this? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Regardless that you turned on VS2010 settings to breack on all exceptions, it is still possible that debugger will not stop if the excetion is thrown not in your code. You also need to switch off the "Just my code" option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about this setting. Turning off "Just my code" allowed me to find that the problem is a timeout. Since I asked how to debug it, not what the problem was, if you put your suggestion into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it helped :) I have posted this as "answer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless that you turned on VS2010 settings to breack on all exceptions, it is still possible that debugger will not stop if the excetion is thrown not in your code. You also need to switch off the [Just my code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx) option.